# DataGridView CellContentClick event missed if SelectionChanged event handled?

Tags: .net, events, datagridview, event-handling, c++-cli

I'm using C++/CLI .NET 4.5 on Win7. I develop a control with a DataGridView. The cells are not editable by the user neither it is possible to add rows manually.

I need to catch/handle the *SelectionChanged* event, so I added a handler for it. I also need to catch/handle the *CellContentClick* event, so I added too the handler for it. If I click on the content of a cell, of course the selection is changed but I would like to catch the event for the click too. The handler for *CellContentClick* is never called.

- If I remove the *SelectionChanged* handler, the *CellContentClick* is catched as wanted.
- If I put a `return` as the first line of my *SelectionChanged* handler, the *CellContentClick* is never catched neither.

It looks like if the handler for the Selection forbids the event for the click to be fired????

Any idea? Let me know if you need more info about the settings of my DataGridView.

Thanks!

Comment: You surely mis-diagnosed this.  CellContentClick is only raised for cells with clickable content, a button or a link.  Use CellClick instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Hans Passant was right for *CellClick*. I changed *CellContentClick* to *CellClick*.
2. There is a "bug" with the debugger because when I put a breakpoint in the *SelectionChanged* event, the *CellClick* is not catched. When I remove the breakpoint, the *CellClick* is catch. That mislead me. I'm using VS2012.4.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I read this may be a bug with the studio but that is incorrect. it does not fire period. test it and see for yourself.

If you click on the same row the cellclicked event fires. Click on a cell in the previous or next row and the selectionchanged will fire but the cellclicked event will not. Thank you M$.